# Summation of a floored square root

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

I am working on a little something and have hit a roadblock of sorts. I have arrived at this equation:$$\sum_{n=1}^{r}\left\lfloor\sqrt{2nr-{n}^{2}}\right\rfloor$$

I am attempting to find some way of solving this summation as a function of r. If this is possible, could I get some help?

Also, please do not mark this as a duplicate; I searched the existing questions and had trouble finding an answer.

Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: Appears to be http://oeis.org/A036698 .

Comment: Perhaps, but I am not sure...I still don't know how to find a formula, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can rewrite your sum as follows.
$$f(r)=\sum_{n=1}^{r} \lfloor \sqrt{2nr-n^2} \rfloor = \sum_{n=1}^r \lfloor \sqrt{r^2-(r-n)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{r-1} \lfloor \sqrt{r^2-n^2} \rfloor$$
Thus, this counts the number of Gaussian integers $z=a+bi$ satisfying $|z|\le n$, $a>0$, $b\ge 0$.

This is http://oeis.org/A036698 .

Counting Gaussian integers with norm $|z|\le n$ is known as the [Circle Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_circle_problem).  Only bounds are available, not exact formulas.  We can prove that
$$f(r) = \frac{\pi}{4} r^2 + O(r).$$
See the links on the Wikipedia page for proofs.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was working on! Thanks for your answer. I guess there's no exact solution, then. :/